# Click event not firing for dynamically generated button

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am getting JSON data (businesses) from the yelp API. I loop through the data to display the businesses, and upon clicking on a certain business, display more information about it. I also want to include a button that will add the business and its location information to a list to use later on. This is what I have so far:

```
        function display_results(businesses) {
            var options = '';
            for (var i = 0; i < businesses.length; i++) {
                options += '<div class="optbtn" data-value="' + i + '">' + businesses[i].rating.toFixed(1) + "/5\u2606  " + businesses[i].name + '</div>';
            }
            $('#businesses').html(options);

            // display details on click
            $('.optbtn').click(function () {
                var index = $(this).data('value');
                console.log("index: " + index);
                var details = businesses[index];
                console.log(businesses[index].name);

                var info = '';

                info += 'Name: ' + details.name + '<br>';
                info += 'Rating: ' + details.rating + '<br>';
                info += 'Price: ' + details.price + '<br>';
                info += 'Hours: ' + details.hours + '<br>';
                info += 'Location: ' + details.location.address1 + ', '
                    + details.location.city + ', '
                    + details.location.state + ' '
                    + details.location.zip_code + '<br>';

                info += '<br>';
                info += '<button type="button" class="add btn btn-primary" data-value="' + index + '">' + 'Add to List' + '</button>';

                $('#info').html(info);
            });

            $(document).on('click', 'btn', function () {
                console.log("button clicked");
                var d = $(this).data('value');
                console.log("btn: " + d);
            });

        }

        $(function () {
            $("#search_bar").autocomplete({
                source: "/autocomplete",
                minLength: 3,
                select: function (event, ui) {
                    $.ajax({
                        url: "/business_search",
                        type: "GET",
                        data: {
                            term: ui.item.value
                        },
                        success: function (result) {
                            display_results(JSON.parse(result).businesses);
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
        });
```

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="ui-widget">
  <label for="search_bar">Business Search:</label>
  <input id="search_bar" />
</div>
<div class="ui-widget">
  Businesses:
  <div id="businesses" class="ui-widget-content"></div>
</div>
<div class="ui-widget">
  Info:
  <div id="info" class="ui-widget-content"></div>
</div>
```

I am having trouble getting the button to actually work. Additionally, what would be the best way to store the business if I wanted to hold the name, location, and other related information?

Comment: Typo: `'btn'` should be `'.btn'` to select the class.

Comment: You have a typo: `btn` is a class, so the selector should be `.btn`, i.e. `$(document).on('click', '.btn', function () { ... }`

Comment: Thank you!!! Sorry for such a beginner mistake